# Changing relative layout programmatically

Tags: android

I've relative layout i.e. **main.xml** which I set as follows. But now I've to put view1 on view2 with **width=200dp and height =100dp**, so that view2 will be large one and  view1 will be small one on it.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
         {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
         }
```

**main.xml**

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/panel_bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <com.proj.demo.view1
        android:id="@+id/sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/panel_quick_buttons"
        />

    <com.proj.demo.view2
        android:id="@+id/sheet2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/panel_quick_buttons"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What do you want to achieve? If you just want to change width and heigh than:

```
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
    rl.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
    rl.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
```

Comment: then call invalidate() from rl afterwards.

Comment: Nothing happen when I call rl.invalidate(). But it will change after I scroll the screen. Anyway to refresh the whole screed?

Comment: @bagusflyer you can use rl.requestLayout();

Answer (score 0):

I have found some void changes when try to change multiples times the size like this :

```kotlin
relativeLayout.layoutParams.width = size
relativeLayout.layoutParams.height = size
```

So, insted you can use this kotlin function

> Executes block with the View's layoutParams and reassigns the
> layoutParams with the updated version.

```kotlin
relativeLayout.updateLayoutParams {
    width = size
    height = size
}
```